# Coordinates of Document that is Currently Visible on Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I find out the coordinates of the web page / document that is currently visible on my browser? For example, `$(window).height()` returns 700 and `$(document).height()` returns 3,000 i.e. my document is longer than the browser's height. I'd like to find out, after interacting with the page (e.g. scrolling), which area of my document is currently visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery you could do:

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

[`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerHeight)

> Height (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the horizontal scrollbar.

[`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth)

> Width (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the vertical scrollbar.